# Symfony Routing: sf_format default value

Tags: php, symfony1, url-routing, symfony-1.4

Having the following route:

```
  blog_rss_comments:
    url:     /blog/feeds/:type/comments.:sf_format
    param: {module: blog, action: feedComments }
    requirements: { sf_method: get, sf_format: (?:rss|xml|html) }
```

Is it possible to add a default-sf_format setting, so I do not have to pass sf_format every time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`param` is where you can put default values.

```
 param: {module: blog, action: feedComments, sf_format: html }
```